# Free/Open Source WinForms Skinner?

Tags: c#, winforms, skin

I am looking for a Free/Open Source WinForms "Skinner" (like AppFace and IrisSkin).

Does anyone know where I can find such a project? 
If it is able to open .ssk .urf skin files, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a great time with the [KryptonControls from ComponentFactory](http://www.componentfactory.com/)
. Theres a huge set of highly customizable controls for free. The Ribbon and the docking suite costs a few dollars, but they're worth the money.
Unfortunately, the're not able to use the skin files.

Good luck!